# finite set with infinite closure (topology)

Tags: general-topology

-Give an example of a topological space where there is a finite set A such that its closure Cl(A) is infinite

Please any hint for this problem

Comment: Consider the trivial (indiscrete) topology.

Comment: Should I assume infinite set X?

Comment: Omg it's trivial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X$ be an arbitrary infinite set. Consider the ***indiscrete topology*** on $X$. Then closure of every non-empty set is $X$, which is *infinite*.

Answer (score 2):

Particular point topology:

Consider $\Bbb Z$ (or any other infinite set), where a set is open if:

- it's empty, or
- it contains $0$.

What is the closure of $\{0\}$?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: can you think of a topological space with infinitely many points but only finitely many closed sets?

Answer (score 1):

The definition of a topology is very broad. There is nothing in the definition that requires that any neighborhood of a point must exclude any other point or any collection of other points.Example :  Let $S$ be an infinite set, let $T$ be a finite non-empty subset of $S$,and let $U= \{V\subset S : T \subset V \} \cup \{\phi\}$. Then $ U$ is a topology on $S$ ,and the closure of the finite set $T$, in the topology, is the infinite set $S$.

Answer (score 0):

Another example: If $R$ is an integral domain, then the zero ideal is prime.  If $I \subseteq R$ is an ideal, define $C_I = \{ $all prime ideals containing $I\}$.  The sets $C_I$ are the closed sets in the Zariski topology on $\mathrm{Spec}(R)$.  Then the closure of the zero idea (thinking of it as a point in $\mathrm{Spec}(R)$) is the whole space, so whenever $R$ is a ring with an infinite number of prime ideals, you get an example.